# C# append duplicate column name with incrementing number

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a excel file which has some few columns been repeated multiple times. I am loading the excel file to a data table and then doing a bulkcopy to SQL table.

Since the excel file has duplicate header value, the data load to datatable fails.

[image: Data]

Hence I want to add a number programmatically at the end of of header column. for example city_0, city_1, city_2 etc

I tried with the below code and its working for the first duplicate header

```
if (dtSourceData.Columns.Contains(cRowValue) && cRowValue != "")
{
    cRowValue = SuffixValueToString(cRowValue, dtSourceData);
}

private string SuffixValueToString(string strOriginalString, DataTable dtDataTable)
  {
   string strAmendedString = string.Empty;
   var strlastValue = strOriginalString.Substring(strOriginalString.Length - 1);
   if ((char.IsDigit(strlastValue, 0)) == false)
   {
    strAmendedString = strOriginalString + '_' + '0';
   }
   else 
   {
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(strlastValue);
    strAmendedString = strOriginalString.Replace(strlastValue, Convert.ToString(value + 1));       
   }
   return strAmendedString;
  }
```

When the second duplicate value gets into column check it fails as there is already a value with the same name.

Is there a way where I can add number suffixing my string data?